# dplyr top_n remove 0 in summary

Tags: r, dplyr, top-n

How to remove the 0 in the table summary when using top_n with dplyr?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data("diamonds")
diamonds #set diamonds as data.frame

manualTest = diamonds %>%
  count(cut)  %>%
  top_n(3)


table(manualTest$cut)
```

Result

```
 Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
    0         0         1         1         1
```

Expected result

```
 Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
  1         1         1
```

Comment: Not sure is this related to `top_n`... Seems like `table(factor(manualTest$cut))` or something similar should do. Or you could do something like `count(cut = as.character(cut))` instead of `count(cut)`, depends on what your desired class.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `str(manualTest)` you will see that `manualTest$cut` is a `factor` variable. So the solution would be to make it a character. Three options

1)

```
manualTest = diamonds %>%
count(cut)  %>% mutate(cut = as.character(cut)) %>% 
top_n(3)
```

2)

```
manualTest$cut <- as.character(manualTest$cut)
```

then run `table(manualTest$cut)`

3)

```
table(as.character(manualTest$cut))
```